# Accessing React Native Firebase remote input notificationOpen.results when app is not in foreground

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, react-native

After building a notification and adding a remote input and action using react native firebase, the user input doesn't console log when the app is not foregrounded or on screen. At this point, notificationOpen.results defaults to undefined where it would otherwise be populated with the users response after they click send. Below is the code to add the remote input and to listen for the response.

```js
export const backgroundMessageListener = async (message) => {
  console.log(message);
  const { data } = message;
  const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
  .setTitle(data.title)
  .setBody(data.body)
  .setSound('default')
  .android.setSmallIcon('notification')
  .android.setColor(colors.primary.normal)
  .android.setAutoCancel(true)
  .android.setLargeIcon(data.icon)
  .android.setChannelId(data.channel)
  .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max);

  if (!notification.android.channelId) {
    notification.android.setChannelId('misc_channel');
  } else {
    // Build an action
    const action = new firebase.notifications.Android.Action('reply', 'check-mark', `Reply to ${notification.title}`);
    action.setShowUserInterface(false);

    // Build a remote input
    const remoteInput = new firebase.notifications.Android.RemoteInput('input')
    .setLabel('Reply')
    .setAllowFreeFormInput(true);

    // Add the remote input to the action
    action.addRemoteInput(remoteInput);

    // Add the action to the notification
    notification.android.addAction(action);
  }

  // display the notification
  firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);

  return Promise.resolve();
};

export const backgroundActionHandler = async (notificationOpen) => {
  if (notificationOpen.action === 'reply') {
    console.log(notificationOpen);
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same problem. I can get `backgroundActionHandler` just fine, but `notificationOpen.results` is not populated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this following action, and its working. But you need to make
sure that you send the data payload only.

1. Add this to your android manifest xml

```html
 <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.BackgroundAction"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionsService"/>
```

2. Add this file inside src folder with name backgroundMessaging

```js
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
const channelId = 'app-local-notifications';

export const backgroundMessageListener = async message => {
  const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
    channelId,
    'Local Interactive Notifications',
    firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max,
  ).setDescription('Local Interactive Notifications');
  firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

  const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
    sound: 'default', //important
  })
    .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
    .setTitle(message.data.title)
    .setBody(message.data.body)
    .android.setChannelId(channelId) //important
    .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher')
    .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High); //important

  const action = new firebase.notifications.Android.Action(
    'reply',
    'ic_launcher',
    'Reply',
  );
  action.setShowUserInterface(false);

  const remoteInput = new firebase.notifications.Android.RemoteInput(
    'inputText',
  );
  remoteInput.setLabel('Message');
  action.addRemoteInput(remoteInput);

  localNotification.android.addAction(action);
  firebase
    .notifications()
    .displayNotification(localNotification)
    .catch(err => console.log(err)); //important
};

export const backgroundActionHandler = async notificationOpen => {
  if (notificationOpen && notificationOpen.notification) {
    const action = notificationOpen.action;
    const notificationId = notificationOpen.notification.notificationId;
    if (action === 'reply') {
      console.log(notificationOpen);
    } else {
      console.log('unsupported action', action);
    }
    // hide the notification instead of Promise.resolve()
    firebase.notifications().removeDeliveredNotification(notificationId); //important
  }
};
```

3. Add this to index.js from your root project

```js
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => backgroundMessageListener)
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationAction', () => backgroundActionHandler);
```

4. And this to the admin script to send the data only payload

```js
async function sendPushNotification(message) {
try {
    await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
        ['eTlozrPo49U:APA91bEPJhpZPN4rVUjJL93y9PxN5DFKH198RJOSPZ9qHgBenmtcuMIPOmUTZGuFEGc07OxGkgh4OpSyggOr13ud3W9Ipokp61VayZ29sucTuyjHCjDGlNCfTbliwKiN0uDBjpklpOR0'],
        {
            data: {
                title: 'a',
                body: 'a',
                navigation: 'CreateOrderLandingScreen'
            },
        },
        {
            // Required for background/quit data-only messages on iOS
            contentAvailable: true,
            // Required for background/quit data-only messages on Android
            priority: 'high',
        },
    );

    console.log('A');

}catch(e) {
    console.log('Gagal mengirim pesan');
}

}
```